# PHP check_input syntax error

Tags: php, syntax

I'm currently writing a php contact form and I get a syntax error with my check_input : unexpected "," on line 9

```
    l6  $name = check_input($_POST['name'], "Veuillez Indiquer votre nom");
    l7  $position = check_input($_POST['position'], "Veuillez indiquer votre profession");
    l8  $email = check_input($_POST['email']);
    l9  $subject = check_input($_POST['subject']), "Veuillez indiquer l'objet de votre message");
    l10 $message = check_input($_POST['message']), "Veuillez rédiger votre message");
```

Any idea of why it works on lines 6 and 7 and not 9 ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo, RTFM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the closing bracket after the `$_POST['...']` variables in both lines 9th and 10th

```
$subject = check_input($_POST['subject'], "Veuillez indiquer l'objet de votre message");
$message = check_input($_POST['message'], "Veuillez rédiger votre message");
```

Comment: My mistake effectively... Don't know how I managed not to see it... Thanks @matewka